# If Swift will replace Objective-C in the future

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm a beginner at iOS, and just finish studying Objective-C last year. 
However, there is lots of people beginning to study Swift. After reading some related articles, I don't think Swift is more effective than Objective-C. If Swift will replace Objective-C in the future? Is it necessary to study Swift right now? I need your tips.

Comment: My opinion: Swift is still a very young language. Lots of area to improve, but the learning curve is shorter than Objective-C. Good to learn 1 more language, but I prefer Objective-C for my work; I don't want my job tasks get trapped by unknown new bugs in Swift.

Comment: Swift feels a little buggy still... and there's optionals everywhere! All this safety takes some getting used to

Comment: For sure Swift will replace Objective C. Apple has spent over four years developing Swift for something. Objective C is a 30 years old language and obviously needs a replacement.

Comment: I think it's still a good idea to have an almost-complete knowledge of Objective-C before diving into Swift. Otherwise, you might have some difficulties to understand older code and older designs, as you will very certainly continue to encounter Obj-C code for the few years to come. However, Swift clearly appears to be Apple's bet for the language of choice for its future platforms (both iOS and OS X), so try to not stay too far away from Swift while perfecting your Obj-C skills. By the time iOS 9 is released, it might be a good idea to start any new project with Swift as its base language...

Comment: Stackoverflow needs to do a better job of diverting these interesting discussion questions to a forum or something. I get that it is not suited to the Q&A format but opinion/guidance discussion is an important activity of a skilled community. This doesn't seemed to be harnessed with the current model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A complete replacement won't happen in a long time. First there are so many frameworks, open source projects etc. written in objective-c so that Apple isn't able to replace it. But I think that isn't was Apple is planning at all. Apple knows that there are many developer with a long history in Objective-c and they will not force them into a new language. But they try to make Swift as attractive as possible for new developers, but also for experienced devs by allowing for example objective-c code in Swift project and vica versa.

So long story short: You don't need to learn Swift at the moment. But I would give it a go. If you're already experienced in Objective-c it won't take you much time to understand Swift.(Beside the optionals eventually)  If you don't like it, you can still go back and develop in Objective-c again.

Comment: I think (and agree with many above) that this is the right time to learn swift, but it is still a bit too soon to commit to it in production code.